# Compile error when try to initialize a struct from another file with new() function

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I got an error when I tried to initialize a struct named `Alpha` which is defined and implemented in another file.

In `alpha.rs`:

```
pub struct Alpha {
    age: i32
}

impl Alpha {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Alpha { age: 0 }
    }
}
```

In `main.rs`:

```
mod Alpha;

fn main() {
    let alpha = Alpha::new();
}
```

However an error as following was shown when I try to compile the code.

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `new` in module `Alpha`
  --> src/main.rs:81:24
   |
81 |     let alpha = Alpha::new();
   |                        ^^^ not found in `Alpha`
```

Is there any idea about the error?

I've put the struct and its implementation into `main.rs` and it worked, but putting them together isn't desired.

Comment: Have you read the error message? It's telling you that you're looking for the `new` function in the `Alpha` *module*. If the problem was not finding the function in the struct it'd be telling you that it can't find the method in the *struct*. The struct is inside the module, so you either need an additional segment to your path, or to `use` the struct from the module. Also why is `Alpha` capitalised in the `mod` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

`Alpha` is the module. It contains the `Alpha` struct, which has the `new()` function. So, `Alpha::Alpha::new()`.

Also, in Rust, [we name module with `snake_case`](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html). If you do that and change `mod Alpha;` to `mod alpha;` you can also `use alpha::Alpha;` at the top then refer to an unqualified `Alpha::new()`.

Answer (score 1):

In Rust Lang, module names should start with a lowercase or snake_case letter by convention.

In your main.rs, you should use a lowercase name for the module when importing it, like this:

```
mod alpha; // Use lowercase

fn main() {
    let alpha = alpha::Alpha::new();
}
```